# Add value from ajax to textarea

Tags: ajax, textarea

How can I add value from ajax to textarea.

```
$.ajax
        ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/include_active_detail.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
            {
                $("#popup_detail").val(response);
            } 
        });
```

It seems to work with a simple `<p></p>` tag but not with textarea.

Comment: what you are getting in response? console.log(response);

Comment: Nothing. I have no error.

Comment: i meant, did you check by adding console.log(response); inside success function?

Comment: As @RE350 commented, search for the response value, normally if it's a single value it could be console.log(response.YOURVALUE);

Comment: I am getting the right value in the console.log but it is not displaying inside the textarea.

Answer (score -1):

Textarea has no value, you just need to use jquery .text() method for insert.

Therefore exchange:

```
$("#popup_detail").val(response);
```

for:

```
$("#popup_detail").text(response);
```